# GCP shows No Organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

We have migrated to GSuite having used the GCP for a number of projects already.

As some accounts already existed, we transferred these over to our new GSuite tenure.

We now want to transfer the projects to our new Organization but it shows "No Organization" when we try and migrate:

[image: Trying to migrate a Project]

When we try and make a new Project no Organization is shown:

[image: Make a new project]

The account does belong to our Organization:

[image: My Account]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Sorted - I needed to login as another user on our tenure, create a trial which made our organisation!

So when you migrate to GSuite, if you already have a GCP account it then doesn't make an Organisation!

Comment: The issue you faced is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization#acquiring). An Organization resource is automatically created the first time a user associated with a G Suite domain creates a project or billing account. The Organization will be linked to your G Suite account with the project or billing account set as a child resource. All projects and billing accounts created under your G Suite domain will be children of this Organization.

Comment: I also recommend scratching project name from the screenshots by editing your post, project name is confidential to authorized persons only. This post is accessible by public.

Comment: After creating the new user and activating the GCP trial, there is a lag until the organization is created.  It took a few minutes for me, and then I got an email saying it was created.

Comment: @JohnMichelau Any idea how to do this if you *don't* have GSuite? My organization doesn't use GSuite, but we did sign up for Cloud Identity instead.

Comment: @ScottCrooks, I wish I could help you.  I think you'd have to discuss with Google Support, which is fairly responsive in my experience.

Answer (score -2):

No organization is actually someone else's organizations nameSo if you're the owner maybe you need to talk to the owner of the owner of (no organization)