# Cant create a new project on google cloud console - "You must select a parent organization or folder"

Tags: console, cloud, project, new-operator

I am trying to create a project in google cloud console, but when I go to "New Project" option the following message appears: "**You must select a parent organization or folder.**"

[image]

If I press "Browse" option what I see is a "No Organization" item with a warning icon, that I cannot select:

[image]

In the past I could do this without problem, is this a new feature from google?
What I'm doing wrong? 
I need to activate some API Keys to my project

Comment: Possible dublicate?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/51836367/1016987

Answer (score 10):

In my case, it was a permission issue.

after giving the Project Creator, I was able to do add project under organisation.

[image]

In case you are working with folders, you also need to give yourself the permission of "Folder Admin".

For whatever reason, these permissions are not contained even in the role of an "organization admin", but you can grant them to yourself.

Comment: Can you break this down a bit? Where did you navigate, and what exactly did you do? It's been a while since I've done anything with the Google Maps API and the console looks like AWS these days.

Comment: @Philip You need to grant the "Project Creator" role in IAM if things are not changed; I answered it 3 years ago ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hamburger Menu > IAM & Admin > Manage Resources.

Click the checkbox on the Resource you need permissions for.

From there I think you need to assign the right roles. Use your email address as the new principal.

[Here's a screenshot of the permissions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1djg.png)

You may need several of those permissions but it got me going eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I got there in the end. Go to [the burger menu in the top-left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn4Ag.png). This will list all the permissions available. Scroll through each. I turned on all cloud-based permissions. (With the blue pin.) This fixed the issue.

If anyone wants to narrow this down to the exact permission that would be great; I just went for the shotgun approach.